# SQL Single Column Table

Tags: sql, database, data-modeling, erd

I have a model where a Shipment can have many Products through a `product_shipments` lookup table.
The Shipment model also has a relationship where a shipment can have one to many `bill_of_lading` numbers.

Is it proper to create a new table for just `one bill_of_lading` field ?  Most cases a shipment will have only **one** `bill_of_lading number`, but often a shipment will contain **2** or **more**.

There are no other attributes for a `bill_of_lading` that need to be tracked other than just the number.

What is the proper way to handle this case? 
**Normalization rules** would suggest pulling this out into its own table , correct ?

Comment: 'It often contains 2 or more'. The question I ask myself is "If it was more than 2 then were would I store that data"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I would suggest you to do the same thing as you did with Shipment and Products, i.e. create new table. It is a proper way of doing it and easier for you to query later on and even altering your table structure should you need to.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it wouldn't have one column, it would have two... a shipment ID and a bill_of_lading number.  It could be correct to have a table with just those two fields.  It could also be correct to create a field with bill_of_lading, shipment, and product if you can explicitly divide the products into individual bills of lading.  It depends really on the relationship between bill_of_lading and product.

Comment: the relationship would be between shipment and bill_of_lading.  a bill of lading is a manifest, a term passed down from the nautical era  where shipment contained many products for transport

Comment: Right, the bill of lading is a collection of products, right?  So is there a hierarchy... a shipment is made up of bills of lading that are made up of products?  If so, then you only need one table... add "bill_of_lading" to your shipment/product lookup.  Unless there's some reason not to do this, for example if you don't know how many of a product are on which bill... in that case you'd need both two-column tables (shipment/product and shipment/bill_of_lading).  Do you have sample data examples you can post?

Comment: I don't think it should go in the product_shipments table because having more than one bill of lading number comes from the following scenario.  Product(s) loaded at warehouse 1, bill of lading number generated for that initial load.   More product(s) picked up at warehouse 2, another bill of lading is generated for that second loading even though it is on the same truck.  The destination company requires a bill of lading number for each warehouse their products are picked up so they know where raw materials came from.

Comment: Yes, but if you only have bill_of_lading number in a table by itself, you can't tell _which_ products were loaded at warehouse 1 and which were loaded at warehouse 2.  If that's acceptable and you just want a list of bills, then the "one-column" approach is OK.  If you want to know which products were loaded from which warehouse, you need to join product to bill of lading without losing fidelity at the shipping (truck) level.